# Gitlab - Separating CI from Deployment

Tags: gitlab

We are currently using Jenkins, and planning to migrate to Gitlab.  We actually have 2 Jenkinsfiles in each repo, 1 is setup as a Multibranch pipeline and runs on all changes.  Its is the merge check, that runs all the various linting, tests, building the docker containers etc.  The second Jenkinsfile is only ran manually from Jenkins, it takes in all the various input parameters and it deploys the code.  Which is mostly coming in from say, the linted Ansible/Terraform and selecting a docker image that would have already been built via the CI side of things.

I know gitlab doesnt support this model, but this project is already MVP'd so re-working how the dev's combined their logic and deployment code together is probably not going to happen.

Is it possibly, in 1 gitlab-ci.yml file to say `run these jobs on merge/pushes` and only run `this on manual deployment` .

e.g.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'

stages:
  - test
  - test
  - deploy
  - destroy

test-python-job:
  stage: test
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script:
    - echo "Test Python"
    - black
    - bandit
    - flake8
    - tox

test-terraform-job:
  stage: test
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script:
    - echo "Test Terraform"
    - terraform validate --yadda

test-ansible-job:
  stage: test
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script:
    - echo "Test Ansible"
    - ansible-lint --yadda

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    DEPLOYMENT_ID: "Only deploy-job can use this variable's value"
  secrets:
    DATABASE_PASSWORD:
      vault: production/db/password@ops
  rules:
    - when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Terraform Deploy"
    - terraform deploy
    - ansible-playbook yaddas

destroy-job:
  stage: destroy
  variables:
    DEPLOYMENT_ID: "Only destroy-job can use this variable's value"
  secrets:
    DATABASE_PASSWORD:
      vault: production/db/password@ops
  rules:
    - when: manual
  script:
    - terraform destroy
```

We have not even deployed gitlab yet, so im writing that off the top of my head, but I want to know what level of pain I am in for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options to achieve your goal with minimized configuration effort:

1. Working with private jobs and use inheritance or references for easier configuration - doable in one file
2. Extract parts into child pipelines for easier usage

### reduced Configuration in one File

I assume you most hate that you have to redefine the rules for your jobs. There are two ways how you can reduce those duplication.

#### Inheritance

Can reduce a lot of duplication, but can also cause problems, with unintended side behaviour.

```yaml
.test:
  stage: test
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

test-python-job:
  extends: .test
  script:
    - echo "Test Python"
    - black
    - bandit
    - flake8
    - tox

test-terraform-job:
  extends: .test
  script:
    - echo "Test Terraform"
    - terraform validate --yadda

test-ansible-job:
  extends: .test
  script:
    - echo "Test Ansible"
    - ansible-lint --yadda
```

#### Composition

By using `!reference` you can combine certain aspects of jobs see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#reference-tags

```yaml
.test:
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

test-python-job:
  stage: test
  rules:
     - !reference [.test, rules]
  script:
    - echo "Test Python"
    - black
    - bandit
    - flake8
    - tox

test-terraform-job:
  stage: test
  rules:
     - !reference [.test, rules]
  script:
    - echo "Test Terraform"
    - terraform validate --yadda

  stage: test
  rules:
     - !reference [.test, rules]
  script:
    - echo "Test Ansible"
    - ansible-lint --yadda
```

### Parent Child pipelines

Sometimes it might be also suitable to extract functionality into child pipelines. You can easier control what is happening at one stage, when you call the child pipeline and gain overview due to fewer lines of codes. It adds complexity to your builds. But generally it will generate a cleaner and easier to maintain ci structure (my opinion).

This approach will only add the child pipeline when needed - furthermore, you could also centralize this file, if it is similar for the deployments

.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'web' #maybe also useful, as it will only happen on a web interaction
      when: manual
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule' #maybe also useful, for schedules
```

Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    DEPLOYMENT_ID: "Only deploy-job can use this variable's value"
  secrets:
    DATABASE_PASSWORD:
      vault: production/db/password@ops
  script:
    - echo "Terraform Deploy"
    - terraform deploy
    - ansible-playbook yaddas

destroy-job:
  stage: destroy
  variables:
    DEPLOYMENT_ID: "Only destroy-job can use this variable's value"
  secrets:
    DATABASE_PASSWORD:
      vault: production/db/password@ops
  script:
    - terraform destroy
```

### Sidenotes

This is not 100% answering your question, but it shows you a lot of flexibility, and you will soon realize that mimicking jenkins is not 100% ideal. Eg having deployment jobs directly attached to a commit, and visible on that one, allows for a better overview of what was exactly deployed. If you need to run such things manually, i highly recommend to use schedules with preconfigured values, as they only have a play button. Also you have the artifacts already in place and build from your pipeline, why not add additional steps utilizing them, instead of providing this information

I hope my insights will be useful to you, and happy migration ;)

Comment: > you will soon realize that mimicking jenkins is not 100% ideal.

I totally agree, but the project is to re-create the Jenkins setup in Gitlab.

No matter how much i hate the setup, the way things are, is that the terraform/ansible code for each `app` reside in their own dir. So when dev1 deploys, they run a pipeline which runs the TF, and the Ansible, feeding in the proper inputs.  So you and I would use the same pipeline, to deploy the same code, passing in different input parameters like `environment` and `deploymentid`.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 15.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/04/22/gitlab-15-11-released/#define-inputs-for-included-cicd-configuration) (April 2023) provides another tool to separating CI from Deployment

> ### Define inputs for included CI/CD configuration
>
> Previously, if you wanted to change the behavior of included CI/CD configuration, like a CI/CD template, you may have used global CI/CD variables.
>
> However, using global variables applies to the entire pipeline, not just the included configuration, which was not always desirable.
>
> This release adds the ability to declare mandatory or optional input parameters for each includable configuration file.
>
> These input parameters replace the need for global variables and are scoped to the included configuration only, having no impact on the rest of the pipeline.
> This allows you to build more robust and isolated CI/CD templates, as well as declare and enforce constraints. Learn how to use CI interpolation in this [example repo](https://gitlab.com/grzesiek/ci-interpolation-example).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_11/interpolation.png -- Define inputs for included CI/CD configuration]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#define-inputs-for-configuration-added-with-include-beta) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/383375).